# how to many to many model in rails represented in views form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make tag model with post model i want to list tags to choose at the post form and text field to add more tags if not exist and tag to be unique.
if there is an example online that would be more than help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by this [HABTM Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes) because your association should be a **Has and Belongs to many** and then you can add a little remote form to add new tags and refresh the list, this is just the simplest solution, It could be don better with some jQuery plugin like [jQuery tags input plugin](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) but It'd take you some extra time.